# GHC.PackageDb.readPackageDb: inappropriate type (not enough bytes)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When I try to call my project with `stack ghci`, I've got the following error message:

```
~/haskell/timermachine stack ghci
Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /home/developer/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.5/bin/ghc-pkg-8.6.5 --user --no-user-package-db --package-db /home/developer/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/51bdc2ae2d954d767f3325ff96f951609c3c121fc399b49b2efc9de026a236ec/8.6.5/pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
Standard error:

ghc-pkg: /home/developer/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/51bdc2ae2d954d767f3325ff96f951609c3c121fc399b49b2efc9de026a236ec/8.6.5/pkgdb/package.cache: GHC.PackageDb.readPackageDb: inappropriate type (not enough bytes)
```

My stack version:

```
stack ghc -- --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seems like package.cache is corrupted, or something else is deeply wrong. I suggest deleting `/home/developer/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/51bdc2ae2d954d767f3325ff96f951609c3c121fc399b49b2efc9de026a236ec/` and trying again

Comment: I ran into this when using Stack with Nix, and even deleting `~/.stack` did not help. Adding `packages: ["zlib"]` under `nix:` in `stack.yaml` finally resolved it.

Comment: I got this error message after a power outage mid-build probbaly corrupted something. The solution was to delete the offending snapshot (c:\sr\snapshots\<short id>) and then stack build again.

Comment: Me too power outage. On a Fedora Linux system I had `sudo dnf reinstall ghc-compiler` because `/usr/lib64/ghc-8.8.4/package.conf.d/package.cache` had a size of 0 bytes.